# CURL command to create UserStory in rally in a specific Feature throwing following errors

Tags: api, curl, rally

curl -X POST \
  https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement/create \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'postman-token: XXXXXXX' \
  -H 'zsessionid: XXXXXXX' \
  -d '{
   "hierarchialrequirement": {
      "Name": "Test US",
      "Project": "project/XXXXXX",
      "Description": "Test US" ,
      "PortfolioItem" : {
      "_ref" : "portfolioitem/feature/XXXXX" ,
      "_type" : "PortfolioItem/Feature"
    }

}
}'

Response :
 {
    "CreateResult": {
        "_rallyAPIMajor": "2",
        "_rallyAPIMinor": "0",
        "Errors": [
            "Could not read: Could not read referenced object portfolioitem/feature/XXXXXXXX"
        ],
        "Warnings": []
    }
}

i have tried multiple combos of PortfolioItem like

curl -X POST \
  https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/hierarchicalrequirement/create \
  -H 'cache-control: no-cache' \
  -H 'postman-token: XXXXX' \
  -H 'zsessionid: XXXXX' \
  -d '{
   "hierarchialrequirement": {
      "Name": "Test US",
      "Project": "project/XXXXXX",
      "Description": "TES US" ,
      "PortfolioItem" : "portfolioitem/feature/XXXXXX"

}
}'

Response :

{
    "CreateResult": {
        "_rallyAPIMajor": "2",
        "_rallyAPIMinor": "0",
        "Errors": [
            "Could not read: Could not read referenced object null"
        ],
        "Warnings": []
    }
}

i can create US but i just want to add parent feature to it while creating it .

Answer (score 0):

I think you're just missing a leading `/` on your portfolioitem ref.

```
"PortfolioItem": "/portfolioitem/feature/12345"
```

Let me know if that doesn't work!

Comment: didnt work . I have tried it before as well even with entire url as well

Comment: PortfolioItem" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/portfolioitem/feature/1234"

Comment: it might be more related to Object types for example Project has type : project where as Portfolioitem has type : portfolioitem/feature

Comment: i have even tried with                                                       "PortfolioItem/feature" : "https://rally1.rallydev.com/slm/webservice/v2.0/portfolioitem/feature/12234"  Response creates a US with following error   "Warnings": [
            "Ignored JSON element hierarchialrequirement.PortfolioItem/feature during processing of this request."
        ],

Answer (score 0):

i was able to fix it by adding the following ref flags

"PortfolioItem": {
      "_ref": "portfolioitem/feature/XXXXX",
      "_type": "PortfolioItem/Feature"
    }

it worked for me now